# How to test MatDialog using Jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I'm very new in unit test with jest and angular and now I'm trying to do some test with matDialog from Angular Material.

I want to test if the dialog calls afterClosed method and if the method do Search is called.

So we have this method:

**TS**

```
  openUserModal(user?:any){
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    if(user){
      dialogConfig.data = user.data;
    }

    this.dialog.open(ModalCreateUserComponent, dialogConfig)?.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.isShowingTable) {
        this.doSearch();
      }
    });
  }
```

I tried to mock the dialog as below:

**SPEC**

```
    describe('UserComponent', () => {
      let component: SearchUserComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchUserComponent>
      let dialog: any
      let matDialogConfig: MatDialogConfig;
    
    
      const dialogMock = {
        close: () => { },
        open: () => { },
        afterClosed: () => { return of(true) },
      };
    
      beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [SearchUserComponent],
          schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
          providers: [
            { provide: MatDialog, useValue: dialogMock },
            { provide: MatDialogConfig },
          ],
          imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            RouterTestingModule,
            MatDialogModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule
          ]
        })
          .compileComponents();
      });
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchUserComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        dialog = TestBed.inject(MatDialog);
        matDialogConfig = TestBed.inject(MatDialogConfig);
      });
    
      it('should test', () => {
    
        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    
         const user = {
          data: {
            id: 1
          }
        }
    
        const spyDoSearch = jest.spyOn(component, 'doSearch');
        const spyAfterClosed = jest.spyOn(dialog, 'afterClosed');
    
        component.isShowingTable = true;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.openUserModal(user);
    
        expect(spyDoSearch).toHaveBeenCalled();    
        expect(spyAfterClosed).toHaveBeenCalled();    
      });
    });
```

The error that I get in both expect:

> ```
>  expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
>
>     Expected number of calls: >= 1
>     Received number of calls:    0
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure the `doSearch` or the `afterClosed` events ever happen. You never trigger them in the test do you?

Comment: I trigger the openUserModal, but I want to verify if the other two methods is called when I call openUserModal.

Comment: wouldn't `doSearch` only be called when someone searches in the input? Like not just if the modal is opened? I'm not super familiar with matui i'm just asking

Comment: yes I think the afterClosed event must be fired first. maybe you can get the element by its id and use a .click() followed by a fixture.detectChanges() method inside your test

Comment: the do search is trigger after a click in a button.

Comment: I need to have this entire method coverage in my unit test coverage, if I do the button click open test, it will be covered?